# How to set request attributes in JSP and how to get them in a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am setting request attributes in JSP. But I am not getting that request attributes in servlet it is getting `null`.

If I set like `request.getSession().setAttribute();` it is working fine but `request.setAttribute()` means it is getting `null`.

How to set request attributes in JSP without session?

Comment: did you used RequestDispatcher ??

Answer (score 2):

**Request Set Attribute**

```
request.setAttribute("message to be saved",variableName);
RequestDispatcher reqDisp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("servletName");
reqDisp.forward(request, response);
```

By this you will forward the values to the next servlet

**Request Get Attribute Example**

```
<html>
<body>
<%
  String message = (String) request.getAttribute("message");
  out.println("Servlet communicated message to JSP: "+ message);

  Vector vecObj = (Vector) request.getAttribute("vecBean");
  out.println("Servlet to JSP communication of an object: "+vecObj.get(0));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use or suggest scriplets.

Comment: [JSP code conventions discourage it.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far As i understand,you need to pass some values from jsp to servlet.
I would suggest you to use session.setAttribute() and session .getAttribute();

In the jsp try

```
session.setAttribute("test","test");
```

in the servlet

```
session.getAttribute("test");
```

you will get `test`

Comment: Please don't use or suggest scriplets.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis use of jstl/el is a good option but here OP is already using scriplets so I just rectified the mistake

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is in the *JavaServerPages Standard Tag Library* (JSTL):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html.

You want to use the **c:set** element from the core library and set scope to **request**. Example from the docs:

```
<c:set var="foo" scope="request" value="..."/>
```

or from the body of the tag:

```
<c:set var="foo">
     ...
</c:set>
```

Don't forget to declare the tag library at the top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Hope this helps!